# can't login as root on a remote Redhat Server

Tags: redhat, login, sudo, root, su

I am currently working on a remote RedHat server(RHEL version 6.7 x86_64).
I can login as a user by using userID and password which is provided by 
the server administrator.
But when I try to login as root by using command `sudo su` ,the console 
gets hang infinitely.
To get out of this, I have to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> key.
Also when I use `su - root` or `su root`, it shows incorrect password.
This was not the case some days ago.
Earlier I was able to login as root by using `sudo su` and then entering the same password provided by the server administrator.

To resolve this issue,I have done the following things:

1. Checked `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow`, `/etc/securetty` files
2. Also checked `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and `/etc/pam.d/su` files
3. `chmod 4755 /bin/su`
4. `chmod 644 /etc/securetty`
5. checked root account expiry date(not expired)

What else do I need to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you tried to login with "sudo su -" ?

Comment: @Dominic Simard...Yes I tried to login with "sudo su". But the console gets hang..& I have to press ctrl + c key  to get out of that

Comment: You should be using `sudo -i`, not `sudo su`.

Comment: @Michael Hampton...I am using "sudo su" only. I have used it so many times before. But now it is not working...

Comment: Then stop doing that!

Comment: It sounds like someone messed up the permissions on files and you may have missed one.  The right way to fix perms in redhat/centos is `rpm --setperms package_name.rpm` for each related package and assuming you hopefully have selinux enabled, then `restorecon -F -R -v /`    To find the associated packages, use `rpm --whatprovides /path/to/file`

Answer (score -1):

You have to edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and check if *PermitRootLogin* is enabled.

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then restart sshd:

```
~$ sudo service ssh restart
```

Note that is a security hole to allow logging in as root through ssh. Do it for testing purposes only and consider using sudo instead.

Comment: This is not about SSH login, but using su to become root. Asking someone to open SSH root login to get around a problem like this is dangerous advice. It is against best practices and should never be done.

Comment: I agree with you @mzhaase. I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I faced on RHEL9. The solution is simple.
You must have "**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**" config present. If not,
Use your package manager to install ssh service.
For RedHat,

```
yum install openssh-server
```

Now, the config will be created and you should be able to open "**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**" using any editor.
Search for the string "**Authentication**", and add the following line.
"PermitRootLogin yes".
Save and close the file. Do not forget to restart the "**sshd**" service. Then try login with root. Hope it will work if you haven't forgot the root password :D

Comment: The question is not about using ssh